# Why is my function returning NULL?

Tags: php

```
function csv_data_to_zip_array($csv)
{
    $f = fopen($csv, "r");
    $i= 0;
    while($line= fgets($f)){
        $line = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $line);
        if(is_numeric($line)&&strlen($line)==5){ // it is a zip code
            $array[] = $line;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($f);
    return $array;
}
```

That is my function, it's reading a large csv with a bunch of zip codes into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's what [Ignacio said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775044/why-is-my-function-returning-null/7775067#7775067): either the `while` or `if` is always returning false, and you should initialize `$array` as an empty array before that while loop anyway.

Here is a suggestion for maybe getting results faster: If the CSV always contains the ZIP codes in the same column, use `fgetcsv` instead. You can then just specify the column number to check (`is_numeric(substr($line[column_num],0,5))`) rather than running a `preg_replace` on the whole line.

*Edit*:

Using the sample data you posted from your website (I noticed all data files in there have the zipcode in the first column; some files have a header row and some do not), this function does the trick:

```
function csv_data_to_zip_array($csv_path) {
  $fd = fopen($csv_path,'r');
  $zipcodes = array();
  while ($columns = fgetcsv($fd)) {
    if(is_numeric($columns[0])) {
      $zipcodes[] = $columns[0];
    }
  }
  return $zipcodes;
}
```

Comment: it's not really in csv format, there just text documents renamed csv, because that's how they send them down. idky

Comment: @theprestig3, can you please verify that you are now initializing `$array` as an empty array before the `while` loop?

Comment: This is what I have right now returning NULL`function csv_data_to_zip_array($csv)
 {
  $f = fopen($csv, "r");
  $i= 0;
  $array = array();
  while($line=fgets($f)){
   $line = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $line);
   if(is_numeric($line)){ // it is a zip code
    $array[$i] = $line;
   }
   $i++;
  }
  fclose($f);
  return $array;
 }`

Comment: @theprestig3, have you tried using a name other than `array` for your array?

Comment: @theprestig3, you shouldn't need to reference `$i` in `$new_array`. Use the `$new_array[] = $line` technique to push a new value into `$new_array` as you did in the original post.

Comment: made the changes still no results, this is probably one of those things where it's obvious but I'm looking to hard. I'll figure it out soon enough, thanks for the help everyone

Comment: @theprestig3, try the function shown in the edit I made and see if that helps. It works for me.

Comment: actually both functions worked just fine, turns out i forgot to remove the key from the return of another function that was making it return NULL... so yeah, it was another function giving me the problem. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: @theprestig3, well, I don't know what to tell you. I'm using PHP 5.3 (apparently, so is your server), and my function, along with your data files, works. All I haven't seen yet is how you're calling the function/what its output is being assigned to, and how you're dealing with that assigned output. Additionally, you should check and see if the returned array is NULL before the `return` statement is made. i.e., use `print_r` to see its contents.

Answer (score 5):

Because no elements ever get added to `$array`; one of your conditions (`while`, `if`) is always false.

As an aside, you should always initialize non-scalars, but that wouldn't solve your problem here.

Comment: Thanks, I did a test and removed the if statement completely and the array is still NULL. Could it have something to do with fgets?